# How to build an interactive map of an office building?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to design a map of each floor of our office building.  I just need some basic functionality and am not sure where to begin.  I'm building all of this into my angular web app.

I'd like a recommendation on which program to use to design the actual map, with each desk location as it's own clickable object. In angular, I'd like to be able to click or hover over the desk and pull from an inventory spreadsheet we've made to get data on the hardware at that desk location.  I have no idea where to begin, what to use to design the map, and what to use to make each desk clickable.  Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: However you draw it, make sure to export it as SVG. That way you can make the desks (SVG Path) clickable and add handlers. Now you can rephrase your question, and also search this site for `floorplan`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11701461/attach-events-to-svg-paths and search for `SVG click inside path` - that should give you a good start